# Using ArrayFormula on Query with Multiple and Bounded Criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

This question is concerning summarizing a database in Google spreadsheet using a predetermined criteria.

I have a **data table** like so in range A1:B8

```
 A       B
-------------
310    890.00
210    875.00
100    849.00
80     845.00
70     842.00
61     842.00
60     841.00
53     825.50
```

I also have a **criteria table** which specifies the boundaries for the ranges to be used in the merged table. The criteria table looks like this.

```
START    END
------------
210      310
95       200
69       90
53       65
```

The **criteria table** is **derived independently** from the **data table** and as you can see, not all the values in the criteria table are present in the data table.

How can I use ArrayFormula such that the **final table** will have the following data.

```
START    END    MAX    MIN       START VALUE    END VALUE
210      310    890    875       875            890
95       200    849    849       849            849
69       90     845    842       842            845
53       65     842    825.5     825.5          842
```

Here are the starting formulas used to calculate the `MAX`, `MIN`, `START VALUE`, and `END VALUE`

```
MAX FORMULA

    INDEX(
      query(
        { ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(table1!$A$1:$A$8)),
          ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(table1!$B$1:$B$8)) },
        " select max(Col2) 
          where Col1>="& VALUE(table2!A2) &" and Col1<=" & VALUE(table2!B2) & 
        " label max(Col2) ''"
      ),
      1,
      1
    )

MIN FORMULA

    INDEX(
      query(
        { ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(table1!$A$1:$A$8)),
          ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(table1!$B$1:$B$8)) },
        " select min(Col2) 
          where Col1>="& VALUE(table2!A2) &" and Col1<=" & VALUE(table2!B2) & 
        " label min(Col2) ''"
      ),
      1,
      1
    )

START VALUE FORMULA

    INDEX(
      query(
        { ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(table1!$A$1:$A$8)),
          ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(table1!$B$1:$B$8)) },
        " select Col2 
          where Col1>="& VALUE(table2!A2) &" and Col1<=" & VALUE(table2!B2) & 
        " order by Col1 asc"
      ),
      1,
      1
    )


END VALUE FORMULA

    INDEX(
      query(
        { ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(table1!$A$1:$A$8)),
          ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(table1!$B$1:$B$8)) },
        " select Col2 
          where Col1>="& VALUE(table2!A2) &" and Col1<=" & VALUE(table2!B2) & 
        " order by Col1 desc"
      ),
      1,
      1
    )
```

Here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BYWNVPvhfHQL4G3csFjKky2lZ_S0JePnqz3UgkJW0oQ/edit?usp=sharing) to the publicly editable google sheet with the sample data on it.

How can I use `ARRAYFORMULA` in Google Sheets such that the details will be autopopulated for a very **large dataset**.

I have looked at `FILTER` and `VLOOKUP`. But since not all the values in the **criteria  table** are actually in the **data table**, I am having trouble utilizing their ability to work well with `ARRAYFORMULA`. Please enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't found a way with arrayformula either, however you can simplify you existing queries. for example max can be obtained with: =query(table1!$A$1:$B$8," select max(B) where A>="& table2!A2 &" and A<="& table2!B2 &" label max(B) ''")

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want but very much easier:

[image: SO43427734 example]

E1 to F9 is named `ArStart` and used for ColumnC in:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(A2:A,ArStart,2))
```

Output is by pivot table.